# New Firefox version console.log problems

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have Firefox 28.0 running on Mac OSX and am trying to use the console and Firebug.
I have javascript that calls console.log to test values of variables and the progress of
post and get requests.
The error message I am getting is:
The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page.

the code that makes the call:

```
            if(e.target.id == "RL")
              {
               console.log('reloading..')
               location.replace('../dummy.php');
               //return false;
              }
```

(dummy.php is a script that calls header('location:') which redirects back to the requesting page, for the sake 
of reloading.)

so what is doing the disabling?

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is disabling the built-in console and replacing it with its own console.